# TFS 2010 Migration to TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, tfsintegrationplatform, tfs-migration

Im trying to migrate from a hosted service to MSFT free [Team Foundation Service](https://tfs.visualstudio.com/). However this is causing me more pain than it should!

Im using [TFS Integration Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) but im getting conflict after conflict. despite going to an empty TFS project.

Can anyone suggest an alternative approach to this. Im very surprised there isnt an easier option, would welcome all suggestions.

Please note these are hosted solutions that im going from and to and not on prem servers.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so it turns out that the Integration tool wasnt so dumb after all, I was! :) Although I still dont think its intuitive, certainly the whole process could be improved...

Anyway, the conflicts that the tool was presenting me was with the build process templates. Although it is an empty destination project the build templates are created upon project creation.

So I had to cloak this folder and all migrated fine.

[image: Cloak BuildProcessTemplates folder]

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I ran into this too. Since creating a new, empty TFS project also creates the BuildProcessTemplate directory and files, I think just about *anyone* using TFS Integration is going to fight with this. The tool really should anticipate this.